# What parts could be labeled XT and be near a Clock of a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, components, clock, identification

An ice cube maker stopped working with the symptom that the temperature cycles are getting shorter and shorter.

I suspect that the microcontrollers clock is not working properly.

I desoldered a part near the clock and I want to replace it.

[image: This is the part in question.]

It is labeled '4.00 J'. I can not identify the part and google did not put out useful information for me.

[image: This is where I desoldered it from.]

The microcontroller is [this](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/file/2011/product/2010/2/23/342731um_s3x9454_ref10.pdf) one, page 19 shows its pins. The XT component center pin (pin 2) is connected to vss. XT pin 1 os connected to XIN/P1.0. XT pin 3 is connected to XOUT/P1.1.

Most confusing for me is that the XT component has a 'J' printed on it. What does that label mean and what could be my unknown XT component?

Comment: Looks like a ceramic resonator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic_resonator. Probably 4 Mhz. You can probably replace it with a 4 Mhz crystal directly in circuit, and it should work.

Comment: @Zuofu thanks for the comment. Why would that component be labeled 'J' instead of 'M' though?

Comment: No clue, maybe a temperature/grade code...

Comment: The label 'J' is most probably the tolerance designation, and in that case means 5%.

Comment: @Zuofu: No, you can't replace that with a crystal.  Crystals are just bare crystals, meaning 2-pin parts.  That's a 3-pin part with the load caps built in.

Comment: Ah, yes- good point on the load caps. I guess you would need to add those too if you want to replace it with a crystal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a *ceramic resonator*.  It is electrically similar to a quartz crystal, although less accurate.  The advantages of resonators over crystals are that they are cheaper, more mechanically robust, and usually require lower drive power.  The 3-pin variety comes with the load caps built in.

The "4.00" may mean 4 MHz.  The "J" is probably a accuracy or temperature or package code the manufacturer uses in the part number.  Check if Murata has something similar.

Comment: If you have a pile of scrap floppy drives, check them ... they often have that kind of part in them....